# Where can I find "documentary evidence" for App Store Approval for download PUBLIC Facebook Videos?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I developed an application for iOS that allows you to download public videos from Facebook. The application does not allow the download of copyrighted video.
The purpose of the application is the sharing the videos through WhatsApp by using the  WhatsApp's API.

I submitted the application to Apple, and the Review Team has reject it reporting the following notes:

> 8.6 - Apps that include the ability to download music or video content from third party sources (e.g. YouTube, SoundCloud, Vimeo, etc) without explicit authorization from those sources will be rejected
>
> 8.6 Details
>
> We found that your app allows users to download music or video content without authorization from the relevant third-party sources.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please provide documentary evidence of your rights to allow music or video content download from third-party sources. If you do not have the requested permissions, please remove the music or video download functionality from your app.

So, where can I find "documentary evidence" ?
I believe that downloading video public and not copyrighted is admissible, the application does not download any videos copyrighted. How to procure the necessary documentation to Apple?

Here is the simple procedure that carries my application:

1. Login via Facebook: The application therefore has the access token.
2. Check the Link: Check if the link refers to a video on Facebook.
3. Download Video: Using Graph Api application gets the source link of the video. If the video is not public or is copyright the application prohibits the download and returns an error. The code I used is :

   ```
   -(void)requestToFbWithGraphAPI{

   isDownloanding = YES;
   internetReach   = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
   wifiReach       = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
   if(([self check:internetReach])||([self check:wifiReach])){
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

       NSString    *urlString;
       NSString    *token;
       NSURL       *url;

       token       = [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] tokenString];
       urlString   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/%@?access_token=%@", videoId, token];
       NSString *encodedURLString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
       url             = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedURLString];
       NSData* data    = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
       if(data != nil){
           [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(handleFbResponse:)
                                  withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
           isLastAPrivacyViolation = NO;
       }else{
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               statusLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"The privacy of the video set by the\nauthor or the copyright does not allow downloading the video.",nil);
               statusLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
               isLastAPrivacyViolation = YES;
               [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.2
                                     delay: 0
                                   options: (UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                                animations:^{
                                    statusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:231.0/255.0 green:76.0/255.0 blue:60.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

                                    statusLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, -40, SCREEN_WIDTH, 40*2);
                                }
                                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0 target: self
                                                                   selector: @selector(resetFromPrivacyNotAmmitted) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];
                                }
                ];
           });
           isDownloanding = NO;
       }
   });
   }else{
       isDownloanding = NO;
   }
   }


   -(void)handleFbResponse:(NSData *)responseDataFb {

    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                     JSONObjectWithData:responseDataFb
                     options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    urlStringSourceVideo    = [json objectForKey:@"source"];
    descriptionVideo        = [json objectForKey:@"description"];
    urlStringPictureVideo   = [json objectForKey:@"picture"];

    NSDictionary *fromDict  = [json objectForKey:@"from"];
    nameVideo               = [fromDict objectForKey:@"name"];

    if (urlStringSourceVideo) {

   [self downloadVideo];
   }

   }

   -(void)downloadVideo{


    statusLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Download Started", nil);

       [self showCancelRequestButton];

   // Create the request.
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStringSourceVideo]];
    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8.6 states in part: "*without explicit authorization from those sources will be rejected*" meaning you will need to obtain explicit authorization.

Under current US law no copyright notice is required for material to be copyright protected. Thus it follows that explicit permission is required in order to ensure that there is no copyright and/or that usage is permitted.

Documentary evidence would be written permission by the owner to use the material. It is up to the user (you) to obtain this permission. Or there may be information on the site or associated with the material stating what use if any is allowed.

Public availability does not mean that there is no copyright or that the material can be used without permission of the owner.

Comment: So according to what you say I should contact Facebook. Surfing the web I have not found an email address to which request assistance to developers. The site [Developpers Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com) in the support section refers to [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and to a Facebook Group on [Facebook](http://facebook.com), but nothing more.

Comment: Yes, contact Facebook, they may have obtained permission and the ability to pass that along to you. The bad news is that In many or even most cases it may not be possible to obtain permission for the material and Apple will not allow usage in an app due to the lack of explicit permission. Apple is protecting themselves and indirectly the material owners.

Comment: i just got the same rejection notice for my app, specifically for downloading instagram videos. You can try appealing the rejection as well as sending facebook an email and hoping you get a response.  I'm doing both.

Comment: @michael Note that Facebook probably does not own the copyright but may have rights to permit your use. That they would allow a 3rd party to profit from their content is an unknown. If one don't have explicit permission or the permissions are not clearly posted such as Creative Commons, there is no permission. Using other's work without permission is essentially theft.

Comment: Did you guys find any workaround or solution for this?